# Problems with getting data from sqlite database django project

Tags: django, if-statement, for-loop, django-views

Recently i have started to learn programming and can't solve one problem. I know that i am doing something wrong, can anybody help me.
I have Article model, that are connected by a foreingkey to vipusk. Where vipusk is connected to a Year model also by a foreign key. On the top of all is Year model.

I have created couple of articles in my database , random ammount of vipusks and some number of Year. 
When i am trying to get it directly from the databese i got only some of them, i mean one year contains couple of vipusks, and when i am trying to display number of vipusks, i got only 2 each. But i know that one of year contains 4 vipusks. I think the problem is somewhere in views. But i don't know how to fix it

THis is my viev field:

```
def arkchive(request):
    latest_year = YearPub.objects.all().order_by('year_alias')
    for i in latest_year:
        latest_vipusks = Vipusk.objects.filter(vipusk_year=latest_year).order_by('id')
        for j in latest_vipusks:
            articles = Article.objects.filter(article_vipusk=latest_vipusks).order_by('id')

    args = {}
    args['years'] = latest_year 
    args['vipusks'] = latest_vipusks 
    args['articles'] = articles 
    return render_to_response('arkchive.html', args)enter code here
```

and here is what i am  trying to get in my template

```
{% for year in years %}
    {{year.yearpub_int}}
    {% for vipusk in vipusks %}
        <a class='title_vipusk'>{{vipusk.vipusk_int}}</a>
        {% for article in articles %}
            <a class='title_article'>{{article.vipusk_name}}</a>
        {% endfor%}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
def arkchive(request):
    years = {}
    for year in YearPub.objects.all().order_by('year_alias'):
        years[year.yearpub_int] = {}
        for vipusk in Vipusk.objects.filter(vipusk_year=year).order_by('id'):
            years[year.yearpub_int][vipusk_int] = Article.objects.filter(article_vipusk=latest_vipusks).order_by('id')

    return render_to_response('arkchive.html', {'years': years})enter code here
```

Template:

```
{% for year, vipusks in years.items %}
    {{year}}
    {% for vipusk, articles in vipusks.items %}
        <a class='title_vipusk'>{{vipusk}}</a>
        {% for article in articles %}
            <a class='title_article'>{{article.vipusk_name}}</a>
        {% endfor%}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is exactly what i meant and what i neaded